# Trying to import data from CSV file in D3.I am getting an error as "Unexpected End of Input"

Tags: d3.js

Trying to import data from CSV file in D3.I am getting an error as "Unexpected End of Input".

```
d3.csv("path/to/Instance.csv", function (error, data)
{   
  data.forEach(function (d) {
  d.state = parseDate(d.state);
  d.success = +d.success;
});
```

EDIT: Adding CSV file.

```
    date,price
    Jan 2000,1394.46
    Feb 2000,1366.42
    Mar 2000,1498.58
    Apr 2000,1452.43
    May 2000,1420.6
    Jun 2000,1454.6
    Jul 2000,1430.83
    Aug 2000,1517.68
    Sep 2000,1436.51
    Oct 2000,1429.4
    Nov 2000,1314.95
```

Perhaps the lack of 2nd decimal place?

Comment: Sounds like your CSV file is broken.

Comment: Can you post a small example csv-file that breaks your code?